# Creating RedhawkSDR component using liquid-dsp library

Tags: liquid

I want to use liquid-dsp library in redhawkSDR component. Is there a way to do this?
I have tried instructions of following link but unable to drag into target sdr. It says null.javaexception. 
[Using external libraries in REDHAWK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146671/using-external-libraries-in-redhawk)

Comment: Bro, what you are asking is very broad to answer. Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I only want to link liquid-dsp with eclipse (redhawk). It links successfuly when I use it in C or C++ project by Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> GCC C++ Linker -> Libraries
add 
liquid. But there is no option for adding libraries in redhawk component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The liquid dsp library has already been wrapped into a redhawk soft-package library and is available on the [redhawk branch of this repo](https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/liquid-dsp/tree/redhawk). Clone that repo, checkout the redhawk branch, build and install and you can link to it as you would any other redhawk soft-package.